# RxSwift cell register failure

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I use the MVVM architecture and after setting everything up there is no cell in the TableView and breakpoints in the cell file will not get hit.

In my code:
controller:

```swift
 private lazy var tableView: BaseTableView = {
        let tableView = BaseTableView()
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self))
        tableView.rowHeight = 148
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 148
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        }
        return tableView
    }()

let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<MytSection>(configureCell: {(datasource, tableView, indexPath, model) -> UITableViewCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self), for: indexPath) as! MyCell
            cell.model = model
            return cell
        })

viewModel.output
            .items
            .map { [MySection(header: "", items: $0)] }
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: bag)
```

The breakpoint in the cell file was not triggered. I think the cell was not called, but my delegate and datasource are both bound properly.

I'd like to know why.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why your configureCell closures might not have fired; none of which have anything to do with the code you presented. Does it have a reasonable size such that a cell will be displayed? Is your `output` actually outputting anything? There are a bunch of other reasons why it might not be working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that the below code works as expected. So the question is, what are you doing differently? Maybe that `snp.makeConstraints` isn't working the way you think it is. Maybe your `viewModel.output.items` isn't emitting any next events. Maybe your `MySection` is implemented incorrectly...

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds)
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self))
        tableView.rowHeight = 148
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 148
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        return tableView
    }()

    let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<MySection>(configureCell: {(datasource, tableView, indexPath, model) -> UITableViewCell in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self), for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.model = model
        return cell
    })

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Observable.just(["hello", "world"])
            .map { [MySection(model: "", items: $0)] }
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }
}

typealias MySection = SectionModel<String, String>

final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var model: String = "" {
        didSet {
            textLabel!.text = model
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that the model was incorrectly analyzed after I replaced AF with Moya, so the cell was not displayed